# How to allow Ember.js load content from a html content field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a view within Ember.js and it displays some content on the page and inside that field is some html, specifically some script-tags:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/coder/blabla.js"></script>
```

But they're not loading the content. Are there any way to make them load or does Ember.js prevent them from loading?

Actually I'm loading them from a ajax-request, if they were loaded on pageload it would have worked. Maybe you could manually trigger them when they load?

```
$("script").trigger("load");
```

Is it possible in Ember? Or how do you do it?

Comment: Any errors in console? Did you try using `{{{content}}}` instead of `{{content}}`?

Comment: Yes, the triple curly braces are there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write your script as a component that loads the js when it loads:

**components/load-github.js**

```
export default Ember.component.extend({
  doSetup: function() {
    var component = this;
    component.$.getScript("https://gist.github.com/coder/blabla.js");
  }.on("didInsertElement")
});
```

**templates/template.hbs**

```
{{load-github}}
```